# Where are Polkit actions documented?

Tags: permissions, policykit

How does one determine the name of a program (application) for Polkit?

In this example (a file in /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/)

```
[My Muon Permissions]
Identity=unix-group:sudo
Action=org.kubuntu.qaptworker3.*
ResultActive=yes
```

Action identifies the Muon package manager.  Another action I found was org.freedesktop.packagekit.*, which seems to be the "Discover" application, if not more.

There seems to be some sort of hierarchy, and the nodes seem arbitrary.  Where are they documented?

For example, How can I identify the XFE package executable to Polkit?

Comment: Probably the documentation from https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/ should help.

Comment: This is a generic API description, with parameter names not values.  The actions are identified only by title.  E.G. PolkitActionDescription — 'Description of Actions.'  Kind of like the infamous Help for the Help key: "The Help Key".